# iPhone 6 status bar, what is this symbol? See pic

Tags: iphone

What is this symbol? On my iPhone 6, it's on the top by the Bluetooth symbol.[phone with keyboard?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIzOt.jpg)

[image: symbol]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That indicates that "iPhone is set to work with a TTY machine."  See the official iPhone manual for additional information (page 13, 165).

http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1565/en_US/iphone_user_guide.pdf